# How to handle JSON nested lists with python

Tags: python, json

I'm training a dataset on mask rcnn. I've annotated roughly 1500 images on labelIMG tool (https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg).

Long story short, I need to get value of x and y co-ordinates from segmentation list in JSON files.

How can I access the list using Python programming?
OR is there any other way i can use .xml annotation on mask Rcnn.

This is form a dataset converted from VOC PASCAL to COCO. Xml were converted to JSON syntax.

**Code**

```py
import json
import codecs

data = json.load(codecs.open('example.json', 'r', 'utf-8-sig'))

for i in data['annotations']:
    print(data['annotations'][0]) #want to output segmentation values in JSON files
```

**JSON File**

```
{
    "images": [
        {
          "file_name": "out538.png",
          "height": 720,
          "id": 20180000001,
          "width": 1280
        },
        {
          "file_name": "3 0751.jpg",
          "height": 720,
          "id": 20180000002,
          "width": 1280
        }
    ],
    "type": "instances",
    "annotations": [
        {
            "segmentation": [
            [
                935,
                372,
                935,
                554,
                1195,
                554,
                1195,
                372
            ]
            ],
            "area": 47320,
            "iscrowd": 0,
            "ignore": 0,
            "image_id": 20180000001,
            "bbox": [
            935,
            372,
            260,
            182
            ],
            "category_id": 1,
            "id": 1
        },
        {
            "segmentation": [
            [
                743,
                317,
                743,
                480,
                962,
                480,
                962,
                317
            ]
            ],
            "area": 35697,
            "iscrowd": 0,
            "ignore": 0,
            "image_id": 20180000001,
            "bbox": [
            743,
            317,
            219,
            163
            ],
            "category_id": 1,
            "id": 2
        }
    ],
    "categories": [
      {
        "supercategory": "none",
        "id": 1,
        "name": "bike"
      },
      {
        "supercategory": "none",
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Bike"
      }
    ]

}
```

i want values of segmentation list: e.g. 935,
                372,
                935,
                554,
                1195,
                554,
                1195,
                372
but all I'm getting is the error "list indices must be integers or slices, not dict"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `i` variable in your `for i in data['annotations']:` loop will be a dictionary, since `annotations` is a list of dictionaries. In order to access the `segmentation` list, you will need to do something like this:

```
for annotation in data['annotations']:
    segmentation = annotation['segmentation']
    actual_segment_data = segmentation[0]
```

The last line of code is necessary because `segmentation` is a list within a list.

This should return the following: `[935, 372, 935, 554, 1195, 554, 1195, 372]`.

Comment: Great, that provides me the list of all the values.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a dict of dict of ...dicts
So you need the correct key to navigate all the way to segments.

```
annotations[0]['segmentation']
```

should give you the list